# Why is Python data-descriptor not taking precedence over normal class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

In the following example:

```
class Desc:
    def __get__(self, object, type=None):
        print('Descriptor Desc read-mode activated.')
        return object._essence

    def __set__(self, object, value):
        print('Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.')
        object._essence = value


class C:
    essence = Desc()


class D(C):
    #essence = 'MAGNESIUM'

    def __init__(s):
        s.essence = 'STEAM'
        print('Class D object initialized.\n')


o = D()

print(o.__dict__)
print(o.essence)
o.essence = 'ALUMINUM'
print(o.essence)
```

The output is as follows (Sublime Text):

```
Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.    
Class D object initialized.

{'_essence': 'STEAM'}
Descriptor Desc read-mode activated.
STEAM
Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.
Descriptor Desc read-mode activated.
ALUMINUM
[Finished in 176ms]
```

, which is as I expect. But when the class variable in class D is enabled (by un-hashing that line), the descriptor is no longer reached and the class variable is looked-up instead. Then the output becomes:

```
Class D object initialized.

{'essence': 'STEAM'}
STEAM
ALUMINUM
[Finished in 178ms]
```

Shouldn't the data-descriptor in class C take precedence over all other, even if it's higher up the inheritance chain?

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Shouldn't the data-descriptor in class C take precedence over all other, even if it's higher up the inheritance chain?

And maybe that's because you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#summary-of-invocation-logic) and found:

> Data descriptors always override instance dictionaries.

And [also](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance):

> Instance lookup scans through a chain of namespaces giving data descriptors the highest priority, followed by instance variables, then non-data descriptors, then class variables, and lastly **getattr**() if it is provided.

However, your definition of `D`:

```
class D(C):
   essence = 'MAGNESIUM'
```

Overrides the definition of the class attribute defined on super-class C as `essence = Desc()` with `essence` as a simple class attribute with a string value. It no longer is a descriptor and assigning or reading won't reach your code.

Consider:

```
class Desc:
    def __get__(self, object, type=None):
        print('Descriptor Desc read-mode activated.')
        return object._essence

    def __set__(self, object, value):
        print('Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.')
        object._essence = value


class C:
    essence = Desc()


class D(C):
    # essence = 'MAGNESIUM'

    def __init__(s):
        s.essence = 'STEAM'
        print('Class D object initialized.\n')


d = D()
# show all the classes in the method resolution order that have `essence`
essence_found = [c for c in type(d).__mro__ if 'essence' in c.__dict__]
print([c.__name__ for c in essence_found])
# is `.essence` on the first one that was found a descriptor?
print('__get__' in type(essence_found[0].__dict__['essence']).__dict__)


class D(C):
    essence = 'MAGNESIUM'

    def __init__(s):
        s.essence = 'STEAM'
        print('Class D object initialized.\n')


d = D()
essence_found = [c for c in type(d).__mro__ if 'essence' in c.__dict__]
print([c.__name__ for c in essence_found])
print('__get__' in type(essence_found[0].__dict__['essence']).__dict__)
# here the second one is, but it doesn't matter:
print('__get__' in type(essence_found[1].__dict__['essence']).__dict__)
```

Output:

```
Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.
Class D object initialized.

['C']
True
Class D object initialized.

['D', 'C']
False
True
```

For the second definition of `D`, with the redefined class attributes, the method resolution order shows `essence` on `D`, so there's no need to continue to `C`. But the `essence` on that class is not a descriptor.

A descriptor is given the highest priority if it is found, but if the first class in the chain of namespaces has the required attribute. It is not a descriptor, but that doesn't matter. It doesn't say it will search all the way through the chain of namespaces for anything that defines the attribute as a descriptor, and then repeat the search for the next best thing. It says it will find it in the chain of namespaces, and prefer a descriptor over anything else on the first one it finds.

Edit: I ended up rewriting the test that shows what is going on, but am not sure whether it's clearer or not:

```
d = D()
# show all the classes in the method resolution order that have `essence`
# is `.essence` on the first one that was found a descriptor?
# for the second one it is, but it doesn't matter:
print([
    (c.__name__,  '__get__' in type(c.__dict__['essence']).__dict__)
    for c in type(d).__mro__ if 'essence' in c.__dict__
])
```

Output:

```
Descriptor Desc write-mode activated.
Class D object initialized.

[('C', True)]
Class D object initialized.

[('D', False), ('C', True)]
```

Comment: I've read your answer many times now and, yes, I understand your code, but I can't understand the reasoning you gave. What's priority here, If, as you're saying, first one encountered is used? You say the first matched name is used: Where is prioritizing in that? (I'm struggling with:   "A descriptor is given the highest priority if it is found, but if the first class in the chain of namespaces has the required attribute. ")

Comment: The variable `d` is an instance of `D`. In the first case (`essence` on class commented out), you can see that there is only a single class `C` associated with `d` and it has the `essence` data descriptor on it. In the second case (`essence` redefined on class), you can see that there are two classes associated with `d`, namely `D` first and then `C`. Although the data descriptor can still be found on `C` for `d`, `essence` is also found on `D` and no data descriptor is present - so, the data descriptor is not reached when accessing `self.essence` in methods of that instance.

Comment: Okay, so where is "prioritizing" in this case? It's literally first-found, first-used, descriptor or not.    ..?

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer "[first] in the chain of namespaces, and prefer a descriptor over anything else on the first one it finds." Since it finds `essence` on `D`, and since that is not a data descriptor, it's just a plain old string attribute. In the first example, it finds `essence` on `C` (as it directly descends from it), and since it is a data descriptor, it uses that.

Comment: Have a closer look at the pure Python example `def object_getattribute(obj, name):` in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance), it shows exactly how the prioritization functions, once it finds a class that has it.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the data-descriptor in class C take precedence over all other, even if it's higher up the inheritance chain?

No, since

```
class D(C):
   essence = 'MAGNESIUM'
```

creates a name `D.essence` (on the class, not on instances), and since that name is a thing, the superclass chain is not followed to find `C.essence` (which is a descriptor).

Comment: but the Python docs says: "Instance lookup scans through a chain of namespaces giving data descriptors the highest priority, followed by instance variables, then non-data descriptors, then class variables, and lastly __getattr__() if it is provided."

Comment: As I said, since you've overridden what `essence` is for `D`, the visibility of `C.essence`, the descriptor, isn't a thing.